# How to increase Wizard Level/rank

Tags: tricky-towers

According to the [faq](https://www.trickytowers.com/faq.php), there's a bunch of different levels/ranks/titles for your wizard. But nowhere can I find how to actually increase this.

I thought maybe online games would contribute to it, but haven't managed to find a game to test it out. Also tried doing the trials, but that doesn't seem to increase it either. Is there a way to increase it for single player/friends play?

Comment: +1 because I love this game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those ranks/titles are obtainable only playing online games. You gain some points after each match, more points for better positions.

As you can see in the lower part of this screenshot found online:

[image]

Also, from personal experience. I've got a couple of ranks only after those few matches I played in order to get some PS4 trophies.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame since it's so hard to find online games.

Comment: @Aequitas I see.. I played it in 2018 and servers were not dead yet